# Trying to increment an integer in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

Good Evening,
I am trying to increment an integer that I have index position of '0' in my array, each time my function gets called. I have the variable added with .push, but then I just want to add one to that. I am trying to use indexof(), I have also tried findIndex(). Below is my code

```js
  const addFunction = async () => {
    var storage_array = await AsyncStorage.getItem(ASYNC_STORAGE_KEY);
     try {
       if(storage_array) {
         storage_array = JSON.parse(storage_array);
         let flow_complete = 0;
     

 
         var foundIndex = storage_array.indexOf(flow_complete);
         console.log(foundIndex);
         storage_array[foundIndex] = flow_complete++;

        await AsyncStorage.setItem(ASYNC_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(storage_array));
         console.log('THIS IS THE ASYNCSTORAGE', storage_array);

       } else {
        flow_complete = 0;
        console.log('Storage array is empty')
       }
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Need a bit of clarification.  When your function is called, you want the first element of storage array to be incremented? What you seem to be doing right now is looking for whatever index the value of `flow_complete` (which is always zero) has and setting that to `flow_complete++` which will always be one. I presume this is not what you intend to do.

Comment: Also, could you put in a sample of what you expect your `storage_array` to look like?

Comment: theJuls this is correct that is not what I am trying to do. The array looks like [0, "show_flow_explanation"], and I want to increment the number 0 each time the function is called.

Comment: Would storage_array.splice(storage_array.indexOf(flow_complete), 0, flow_complete++); work?

Comment: I don't know, I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. Definitely need a rewording on what your objective is in that block of code. Also, don't forget to update your post with what you expect `storage_array` would look like at this point.

Comment: I posted a comment with the how the array looks and the objective is to take the number ‘0’ that’s in the 0th position of the array and increment it by 1 each time the function runs.

Comment: Ohh my bad! Somehow skipped that comment for some silly reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the re-wording of the issue with your comment:

> [...] the objective is to take the number ‘0’ that’s in the 0th position of the array and increment it by 1 each time the function runs

The first issue I see is that you may be misusing the `indexOf` function. That will not give you the index of an array, but instead the position of a particular value of an array.

Example:

```js
const arr = [9, 2, 7, 14]
const index = arr.indexOf(9) // This will be 0, because the index of the number 9 in this array is 0 
const otherIndex = arr.indexOf(7) // This will be 2, because the index of the number 7 in this array is 2
```

So, for you to access the element in the 0th position, you will want to do `arr[0]`. So in your code you will want to do the following:

```js
storage_array = JSON.parse(storage_array);
let flow_complete = 0;
     
// notice there is no need to get the `indexOf` 0 since you do want the position 0 
storage_array[0] = flow_complete++;
```

Now... This will have a second problem which is your usage of the incrementation operator `++`. Although this will increment the `flow_complete` variable, it does not return it to set `storage_array[0]` as you intend to do so.

To fix this, all you have to do is increment `flow_complete` prior to assigning it to `storage_array[0]`. It will look something like this:

```js
let flow_complete = 0;

flow_complete++;
storage_array[0] = flow_complete
```

However, if my interpretation of your comment above is correct, there is one more problem, which you are assigning `flow_complete` to `storage_array[0]` each time the function runs. `flow_complete` is set to 0 as you can see in your own block of code within the scope of your `addFunction`, so this means it will always go back to `0` every time it is run.

Going back to your original comment, you want to increment the value in the 0th index of `storage_array`, not `flow_complete` itself, correct?
If this is the case, you can completely get rid of the `flow_complete` variable and instead increment `storage_array[0]`. This will make your if-block look as follows:

```js
 if(storage_array) {
         storage_array = JSON.parse(storage_array);
     
         storage_array[0]++;

        await AsyncStorage.setItem(ASYNC_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(storage_array));
         console.log('THIS IS THE ASYNCSTORAGE', storage_array);

       }
```

Comment: Thank you thejuls for that very informative answer I am going to give your code a try and I will keep you posted, but honestly that was very helpful thank you.

Comment: Glad to help! :) Will adjust it as necessary if there are any further issues on your end.